# select takes a long time

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have an SQLite database that I have used to log testdata over a weekend.

The database has 7 tables, the main one (and largest) is `main_table` with over 14 million rows and 21 columns. One of the columns is a blob containing 400 bytes in each entry. The database is 13.2GB in total.

Performing queries using the primary key of `main_table` works fine, but if I try any other queries, they take a very long time to complete. Running the following using the sqlite3.exe CLI tool took around 15 minuts (I didn't time it):

```
sqlite> select max(temperature) from main_table;
```

Is this to be expected? Would it likely be faster using a different database?

Comment: You should be looking at indexes rather than alternate dbms. PK queries are fine since that's already indexed, look at the other columns you want to query.

Comment: @OwlsSleeping I'm sorry I'm new to databases so I'm not familiar with all the lingo. What do you mean my "alternate dbms" and "PK queries"? Thanks!

Comment: If you don't have an index on temperature it means that SQLite has to make a full table scan of your main table (so reading sequentially 14 millions of rows) to retrieve the max value. This is probably your issue

Comment: Sorry, PK=Primary Key. DBMS=Oracle,MS Sql server, SQLite etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try below index

```
CREATE INDEX temperature_idx ON main_table (temperature);
```

Check query performance after create index.